# Cannot access new App in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, app

My problem started as follow:

1. I installed SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2012.
2. When I first try to deploy a SharePoint hosted app I got the following compilation error in visual studio

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': App
>   Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed.

1. So I performed these steps mentioned inside this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179923

Now the App will be published successfully, but if I try to access the App from SharePoint using the login local administrator or the SPManagedAccount user; a blank page will be displayed after being prompted to enter username and password multiple times.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Just disable Loopback Check - solved the problem for me.

Here's some PowerShell to do this:

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -value "1" -PropertyType dword
```

[Source](http://www.techtask.com/sharepoint2010/loopback-check-in-sharepoint-2010-ausschalten-disableloopbackcheck/)

Keep in mind, that Loopback Check is essentially a security feature. Disabling it in a productive environment should only be considered if it has an impact on the normal usage and not for debugging reasons.

[Additional Information](http://www.dynamics101.com/2013/06/sharepoint-loopback-checking/)

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of reasons why this may happen.

1. Loopback check needs to be set properly as per Mx. Answer.
2. Super Reader and Super User accounts need to be set.

   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   SET ACCOUNT NAMES (Replace Domain and UserName)

   ## SUPER USER ACCOUNT – Use your own Account (NB: NOT A SHAREPOINT ADMIN)

   $sOrigUser= “blue\SP_SuperUser”
   $sUserName = “SP_SuperUser”

   ## SUPER READER ACCOUNT – Use your own Account (NB: NOT A SHAREPOINT ADMIN)

   $sOrigRead = “blue\SP_SuperRead”
   $sReadName = “SP_SuperRead”

   $apps = get-spwebapplication 
   foreach ($app in $apps) {
      #DISPLAY THE URL IT IS BUSY WITH
      $app.Url
      if ($app.UseClaimsAuthentication -eq $true)
      {
       # IF CLAIMS THEN SET THE IDENTIFIER
       $sUser = “i:0#.w|” + $sOrigUser
       $sRead = “i:0#.w|” + $sOrigRead
      }
      else
      {
      # CLASSIC AUTH USED
        $sUser = $sOrigUser
        $sRead = $sOrigRead
      }

   # ADD THE SUPER USER ACC – FULL CONTROL (Required for writing the Cache)
      $policy = $app.Policies.Add($sUser, $sUserName)
      $policyRole = $app.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPolicyRoleType]::FullControl) 
      $policy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($policyRole)

   $app.Properties[“portalsuperuseraccount”] = $sUser
      $app.Update()

   # ADD THE SUPER READER ACC – READ ONLY
      $policy = $app.Policies.Add($sRead, $sReadName)
      $policyRole = $app.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPolicyRoleType]::FullRead) 
      $policy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($policyRole)

   $app.Properties[“portalsuperreaderaccount”] = $sRead
      $app.Update()

   }
   REf: [Sharepoint-powershell-to-configure-superuser-and-superreader-accounts-on-all-web-apps/](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2014/09/29/sharepoint-powershell-to-configure-superuser-and-superreader-accounts-on-all-web-apps/)